# Transform a macro parameter name to use as a function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to mangle a name passed to a macro to use it as a name of a function. For example I have a macro called `foo` as below:

```
#define foo(name) void name(const string& in) { \\do something }
```

But I want this macro to be called with parameter like this `foo(Bar::do)` so I have to change the name to the proper one to use it as a function.

Is there any way to able to implement this? I use c++11 and g++5.x.

**Edit:**

The problem that I encountered is because of having an old version of a macro, that it could be used with no restriction, so now I have many parts in my code that uses a macro such as `foo(Bar::do)`, but now I have to generate a function using these names but the function names must be distinctive, so I decided to use macro input parameter as a function name, but I encountered the problem I explained.

This is an example:

```
void Bar::do(some_parameters)
{
   FOO(Bar::do);
}
```

This is the part of code that I had before, now I want to add a second macro above this part, like this:

```
FOO2(Bar::do)
void Bar::do(some_parameters)
{
  FOO(Bar::do);
}
```

The both names must be the same, but the `FOO2` must generate a function based on the input parameters.

**Edit2:**

I try here to explain the problem more accurate. 
Before, I had a macro like this:

```
#define FOO(name) \
   some codes here
```

But now I want that have a macro which able to expand as below:

```
#define FOO2(name) void proper_fcn_name(name)(const string &name){ do the same thing here}
#define FOO(name) proper_fcn_name(name)(#name)
```

Which I can use that like this:

```
FOO2(some_name)
void Bar::fcn()
{
  FOO(some_name); 
}
```

And if `some_name` was in the format of `Bar::fcn` I want that `proper_fcn_name` changes that to for example `Bar_fcn`. In final I wish to have something like this, if `some_name` was `Bar::fcn`:

```
void Bar_fcn(const stirng& name) { }
void Bar::fcn()
{
  Bar_fcn("Bar::fcn");
}
```

I must mention that `Bar::fcn` is just a name but I have to consider this because my library users used this style before.

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want the macro to do/produce that it isn't now.

Comment: I want to change `Bar::do` or even `Bar do` to `bar_do` or something like that which able to use as a function. It is something like a name mangilng.

Comment: Why are using a macro, instead of something like `std::function`?

Comment: That looks like you want to use macro definition instead of method template

Comment: What is the larger problem you are trying to solve? Why do you want to do this (whatever this is)?

Comment: No, you can't take unknown pieces of a name and rearrange them unless the pieces are separate macro arguments. Still, I don't see much benefit.

Comment: I had an old macro that I use it for putting some point in my program and get some information. This macro could be called with no restriction, so now it is used with general names like `Bar::do`, Now I have to generate a function by using this macro, but the function names must be distinctive so I try to use the input name as a function name and so the problem occurs.

Comment: `foo(Bar::do)` can define the function `do` of `class Bar`, or `namespace Bar`. but in case of `class` how will you declare `do` inside `class Bar`?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please provide relevant source code, expected output, actual output andd error messages.

Comment: @n.m. Please consider the edit note.

Comment: I believe he is saying he wants a macro that given an input `namespace::member` (where namespace might be a namespace or a class) it would be able to output a valid, unique, function name. E.g. `MYMACRO(A::b)` might produce `A_b_stub`, but I don't understand if it also has to cope with `MYMACRO(x)` and `MYMACRO(ns::cls::mbr)`

Comment: @kfsone Thanks for your comment this is exactly what I were trying to explain.

Comment: So more properly speaking this isn't 'mangling', it is just prepending a namespace?

Comment: @EJP transforming, perhaps. The namespace is included in the macro parameter (`MACRO(ns::mbr)`)

Comment: I agree it is more proper. May be the title must be changed.

Comment: @kfsone  I changed the title, I have been used the mangle because I assume that currently compiler is doing something like that and may be it is possible for a developer to use that capability in his program.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz your latest edit does clarify what you want. But I still have to ask regarding `But now I want that have a macro which able to expand as below` : Why do you want to have the macro contents in its own function? If it's not called anywhere else then why would you not prefer just having to call one macro instead of two?

Answer (score 1):

I was interested by your question and made the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define foo(name) void name (const string& in) { cout << in << endl; }

// function with name bar_do
foo(bar_do)

// function with name bar_do
foo(do_bar)

int main(void)
{
    bar_do("The first test");
    do_bar("The second test");
}
```

In fact it works (it is the output),

> The first test
>
> The second test

but I cannot understand what do you want from that strange usage of macro definition - now that looks like automatic copy-paste approach for producing identical functions with different names.

**UPDATE**

If you really want to use namespace (e.g. `Bar`) consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define foo(name) void name (const string& in) { cout << in << endl; }

namespace Bar{
    void func(const string& in);
}

foo(Bar::func)

int main(void)
{
    Bar::func("The special test");
}
```

You should understand, that namespace have to be defined, and `do` is keyword of C++ language (so, you should not use it as function name)

**UPDATE 2**

If it is possible to change `FOO(Bar::do);` to `FOO(Bar,do);` in your old code, you can do simple substitution to generate `Bar_do` identifiers for call and for definition:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define defgen(class_name,method_name) void class_name##_##method_name(const string& in) {  cout << in << endl; }
#define callgen(class_name,method_name,...) class_name##_##method_name(__VA_ARGS__);

// produses definition
defgen(Bar,do)

int main(void)
{
    // produces call with particular value as an argument
    callgen(Bar,do,"The call test");
}
```

kfsone said (in comments to your question):

> MYMACRO(A::b) might produce A_b_stub

but unfortunately I do not know how (and suppose that it is impossible) to do replacement of `::` with other characters (e.g. `_`).

Comment: @VolAd please consider the edit note I added to post.

Comment: I added a snippet code in my edit note, which may show the problem more clear. The `Bar::do` has not any meaning for me, and some other developers use that for the purpose the they want, and I am not sure that `Bar` is a namespace or a class, I just want to change the name that a developer request from this macro to a name which can be used as a function name.

Comment: "I am not sure that `Bar` is a namespace or a class" This isn't an argument in favour of macros. It just means that you need to put in the effort to create and use a proper naming convention. e.g. I use `this_thing` for namespaces and `ThisThing` for classes. Actually, it's another argument _against_ macros, since people (including your future self) reading your macro-riddled code will soon be saying 'I am not sure what `foo` is or where `bar_do` is declared/defined'. Just use the native language features. Macros should only be used if you have a convincing reason, which IMO this really isn't.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, I want to just write the macro, and I am not the one that uses the macro, in general macro can accept any name, but it is currently used with a convention that I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be stressed enough that you should not do this and this sounds like there's an XY problem here.

You should probably explain the problem in full, why are you trying to generate this function, how is it used, etc.

Anyway enough preaching, here's a work-around:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&)>> g_functions;

#define FOO(name) static void* nonsense##__COUNTER__ =                \
                  (void*)&(  g_functions[ #name ] =                   \
                   [](const std::string& in)                          \ 
                  {                                                   \
                    std::cout << "generated function for : " << #name \ 
                              << " called with arg:" << in << std::endl; \ 
                  });
#define FOO2(name) {g_functions[ #name ](#name); }

namespace Bar
{
    FOO(Bar::func)
    void func()
    {
        FOO2(Bar::func);
    }

}

int main() {
    Bar::func();
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler doesn't have `__COUNTER__` you can sort of use `__LINE__` most of the time (what is one more ugly hack on top of this pile).

Comment: Please look at the Edit2 note of my post. I tried to explain the problem more clear and I think your suggestion does not meet my requirements for solving the problem/

Comment: @MohsenTamiz well I do generate a function just like you wanted to, I just don't give it a name. By using a lambda, I let the compiler generate the name. My solution just has some obvious overhead regarding map-lookup and minor std::function call inefficiencies. But otherwise I don't see how I did not fullfill your requirements.

Comment: Yes now I got it, but I think `#name` inside the lambda function must change to `in`.  Your solution can solve the problem, but as you mention this solution has some obvious overhead that I think I must consider this, If I have not any other solution, yours may be the best thing that now I can do. But first I must look for other possible solution with less overhead.